# Implementing this design in CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid

I am trying to implement the design attached at the bottom. I am going to use CSS-grid to the implement the full design, however, I'm facing some trouble as to how to implement the part I have circled out.
I have thought of separating the left and the right part into separate columns under a single row to implement the overall design.

[Current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p5yY.png)

[Target design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcfC1.png)

I'll attach my existing code below for better reference

```
import "./Content1.css";
export default function Content1() {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-1"></div>
      <div className="col-7 content1-content">
        <h3>Justo Vulputate Tortor Sem</h3>
        <h5>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam deleniti
          aliquam corrupti eius ratione rem veniam. Impedit qui obcaecati minus
          at omnis delectus doloribus suscipit! In nesciunt maiores adipisci
          inventore?
        </h5>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iusto
          reiciendis harum a cumque itaque non, deleniti, reprehenderit maxime
          necessitatibus eum natus magnam, quasi voluptatem sapiente. Harum
          aliquid facilis inventore.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="col-4"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at shape-outside CSS property?

Comment: @AHaworth ah, i wasn't aware if such a property existed, looks like that will work, i'll try and use it, thanks!